# Conjecture: $ \binom{2t}{2a} \geq \binom{t}{a}^2 $

Tags: combinatorics

Experiments using a computer show that the following binomial inequality (which is, to my mind, quite symmetric and natural) seems to be true for all $ a, t \in \mathbb{Z}_{\geq 0} $:

$$ \binom{2t}{2a} \geq \binom{t}{a}^2 $$

Further, it seems that equality holds iff $ a = 0 $ or $ a = t $.

I have tried all the simple methods of proof I can think of:

- looking for a simple combinatorial argument of the form "every method of picking $a$ items from $t$ twice independently can be matched (via some method) injectively with a method of picking $2a$ from $2t$;
- expanding out the subtraction and quotient of both sides in terms of factorials and simplifying (by hand and with Mathematica);
- trying to use induction on $ a $;
- using Google and MSE to find a proof.

Unfortunately I am not that well versed in any inequality methods from enumerative combinatorics, so it is entirely possible one of these methods does work.

> How would one prove this inequality (or is there some counterexample I have yet to find)? I would especially like a purely combinatorial proof, if possible.

Comment: Generalization and proof here : https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3930277/prove-m-choosen-1-m-choosen-2-leq-2m-choosen-1n-2-for-m/3930341#3930341

Comment: Thanks, having seen your answer there it seems obvious... I will flag this as a dupe of that question too.